# Is it possible to enable red squiggles for implicitly defined functions in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022, if I type a code snippet like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    non_existent_function();
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio will not underline `non_existent_function` with red squiggles. I read up on this and it seems it is because an implicitly defined function may eventually be "defined" with a linker. However, I'm wondering if there is a way to enable the red squiggles in this case (or if this is a bad idea, such as causing functions like `printf` to potentially become underlined). I should also mention that I'm attempting to use C with visual studio, not c++.

I looked it up on Google and I'm unable to find any resources that lead to an answer. Additionally, I looked through the text editor, compiler, and linker settings, and nothing jumped out at me. I was expecting some sort of true/false option.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2022 does it. When you hover it shows the problem. You have messed up with the configuration probably. I post it as an answer to show the image.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I was compiling C files, not c++. In my config, it works with c++, but not c.